# Why reducer does not seem to fire in ngrx? How to wire in the reducer to the store?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store

I am trying to dispatch the addHero action in my service:
I see the "obtaining" and "dispatched" messages for each Hero,
but the reducer does not seem to be called.

This is called from an ngOnInit hook.

What is the obvious thing I overlook?

Update: I have wrapped the appReducer to a function which logs each reducer call and then calls the real reducer. I neither see the log of it, so probably I am missing something about how to wire in the reducer.
My attempt was this line in the imports part of module.ts:

```
    StoreModule.forRoot(appReducer)
```

(end of update)

```
export class GetTheActualListOfHeroesService {

  store: Store<AppStore>;

  run(): void {
    console.log("GetTheActualListOfHeroesService")
    obtainHeroesService().forEach(hero => {
      console.log("obtaining", hero)
      this.store.dispatch(addHero(hero))
      console.log("dispatched")
    }
    )
  };

  constructor(appStore: Store<AppStore>) {
    this.store = appStore;
  }

}
```

The reducer is below. I do not see "addHero" in the log.

```
export const initialState: AppStore = {
  heroes: [],
  filterString: "",
  selectedHero: undefined
}

export const appReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(addHero, (state: AppStore, hero) => {
    console.log("addHero", hero)
    state.heroes.push(hero);
    console.log(state)
    return state;
  }),
);
```

The action is defined thus:

```
export const addHero = createAction('add Hero', props<Hero>());
```

And here is my module definition:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroeditorComponent,
    HeroitemComponent,
    HeroListComponent,
    HeroFilterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(appReducer)
  ],
  providers: [
    SelectedHeroRepository,
    HeroFilterRepository,
    GetTheActualListOfHeroesService,
    IsThisHeroSelectedForEditingService,
    SelectHeroForEditingService,
    InitializeStatesService,
    SelectHeroesWithMatchingNamesService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [HeroesComponent]
})
export class Angulartest { }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was this:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({ heroes: appReducer })
```

And the reducer became:

```
export const initialState: Heroes = []

export const appReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(addHero, (state: Heroes, hero) => {
    console.log("addHero", hero)
    const newstate = state.concat([hero])
    console.log(state)
    return newstate;
  }),
);
```